# Drupal commerce change quantity textfield in cart view to selectbox

Tags: entities, commerce

Is there a way to change the quantity widget in the Drupal Commerce cart view from a textfield to a selectbox? And then refresh the page when the selectbox is changed without making the user press the **Update cart** button?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if (strpos($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_') === 0) {
   if (isset($form['quantity']) && ($form['quantity']['#type'] == 'textfield')) {
     $form['quantity']['#type'] = 'select';
     $form['quantity']['#options'] = drupal_map_assoc(range(1,10));
     $form['quantity']'#default_value' => 1,
   }
 }
}
```

?>

Comment: This solution looks like it is for the quantity in the add-to-cart form on a product display page, not the quantity field that shows up in the cart form (View).